# datediff in Hive resulting in Invalid number of arguments error

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, date-arithmetic

I am trying to find login start time, login end time and the total time spent on a webpage in seconds using lead and datediff functions in Hive.

Sample dataset:

| id | login_time |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-05-03 00:20:37.000 |
| 1 | 2023-05-03 00:20:51.000 |
| 2 | 2023-05-03 15:42:31.000 |

Query used:

```
with temp as
(
    select id,
        login_time as start_time
    from login_table
)
select id, 
start_time, 
lead(start_time) over(partition by id) as end_time,
datediff('second', start_time, lead(start_time) over (partition by id)) as time_spent_on_page
from temp
```

But am getting error saying

```
Invalid number of arguments in datediff. Expected 2, found 3
```

Please advise how I can find the time difference between 2 values in seconds on Hive.

Expected output:

| id | start_time | end_time | time_spent_on_page |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-05-03 00:20:37.000 | 2023-05-03 00:20:51.000 | 14 |
| 1 | 2023-05-03 00:20:51.000 |  |  |
| 2 | 2023-05-03 12:00:54.000 | 2023-05-03 12:01:09.000 | 15 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive's `datediff` takes two date strings and return their difference in days.

To get the difference between two datetime strings, we can use `unix_timestamp` twice:

```
select id, 
    login_time as start_time,
    lead(login_time) over(partition by id order by login_time) as end_time,
    unix_timestamp(lead(login_time) over (partition by id order by login_time))
        - unix_timestamp(login_time) as time_spent_on_page
from login_table
```

Notes:

- the `with` clause seems unnecessary, we can just select directly from the login table
- `lead()` needs an `order by` clause

Reference: [Hive date functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=27362046#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions)

Comment: Thank you. How can i get the time spent in seconds?

Comment: @vvazza: well, the query supposedly does that, did you try it?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just tried and it worked :)